# why javascript Inheritance work like this?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

when we are using javascript Inheritance, and a sub Class inherit from its Parent, we always do it like this:

```
var klass = function(){ this.init.apply(this, arguments)};

if(parent) {
    var subclass = function(){};
    subclass.prototype = parent.prototype;
    klass.prototype = new subclass;
}
```

The code above is from 《Javascript Web Application》, i am confused what's its difference with below:

```
var klass = function(){ this.init.apply(this, arguments)};
if(parent) {
    klass.prototype = parent.prototype;
}
```

who can explain it for me?

Comment: `klass.prototype = parent.prototype;` means that the two functions now share the same `prototype` object. So additions to `klass.prototype` will appear on `parent.prototype`. That's obviously not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var klass = function(){ this.init.apply(this, arguments)};
if(parent) {
    klass.prototype = parent.prototype;
}
```

In this code klass.prototype is set to the same object parent.prototype is (parent and klass share the same prototype). Therefore if you do:

```
klass.prototype.myFunc = function() {}

var p = new parent();
p.myFunc // myFunc will be available on all instances of parent (which is bad!)
```

Even worse, if you had

```
parent.prototype.myFunc = function() { console.log('I parent'); };
```

And you try to override the myFunc function for klass:

```
klass.prototype.myFunc = function() { console.log('I child'); };

var p = new parent()
parent.myFunc() // I child
```

You can see why sharing the prototype is a bad idea.

Comment: As your description, if i add parent.prototype.myFunc = function() { console.log('I parent'); }; but i dont rewrite function myFunc in child, then klass cannot call klass.myFunc, is it right?

Comment: @Frankjs It is wrong. klass has access to any function defined on klass.prototype which is the same object as parent.prototype, so it has access to parent.prototype.myFunc. klass does not inherit the method from the parent class, it uses it because they are somewhat combined.